# The roles generated in Keyrock are not really registered

Tags: authorization, access-control, fiware, role-base-authorization, fiware-wilma

I am creating a permission for an application in Keyrock and associating it to user A. When I do a GET request to orion v2/entities (that is equal to created permission), I get a `User token not authorized` message. In the PEP log I can see that the role is not associated to the user:

```
INFO: AZF-Client - Checking authorization to roles [] to do  GET  on  v2/entities and app  629cd23fe9bb42c58d3fde77e0323a7e
```

This is really strange because I added the role containing the specific permission to user A.

Can anyone help with this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the following:

- You are creating the OAuth2 token for the user to whom you have assigned the role.
- You have created the role in the application you are using to generate the OAuth2 token.
- The role has the permission assigned.